# Migrating content from OpenWiki to ScrewTurn Wiki

Tags: wiki, migrate, screwturn

We have a large OpenWiki powered wiki. OpenWiki appears to be a dead project, and ScrewTurn the next best option.

Is anyone aware of a data migration route to move our content from the OpenWiki SQL Server format to the ScrewTurn wiki SQL Server format?

We may end up creating our own (and sharing it) but we'd rather not re-invent the wheel.

Regards,

Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer appears to be a definitive no.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure about the "dead" status?

http://www.facebook.com/pages/OpenWiki-The-Post-It-Note-of-the-Web/145492998806288